# Is this HTML structure and CSS DRY enough in this country selection menu?

Tags: html, css

I have built this conceptual design of a localization menu on this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/jyqzo)

[image: Concept 2]

I am wondering if I should have structured my `<div>`s better or if this should be wrapped in a `<ul>` instead since `<div class="locale">` could be reduced in the CSS with `.international li`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="international">  

  <div class="locale">
    <a href="#"> <!-- link pending -->
      North America
      <div class="americas"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="locale">
    <a href="#"> <!-- link pending -->
      Europe
      <div class="europe"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="locale">
    <a href="#"> <!-- link pending -->
      Korea
      <div class="korea"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="intlButton">
    <a href="#"> <!-- link pending -->
      <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- Planned functionality for production is not shown in this project --> 
</div> <!--/ .international -->
```

**CSS**

```
.international {
  background-color: rgb(36, 30, 30);
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.locale {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.locale a { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }

.americas, .europe, .korea {
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/101702/flags-small.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.americas {
  background-position: 0px 0px; 
  height: 11px;
  width: 48px;
}

.europe {
  background-position: -48px 0px; 
  height: 11px;
  width: 48px;
}
.korea {
  background-position: -96px 0px; 
  height: 11px;
  width: 16px;
}

.intlButton { 
  float: right;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.intlButton a { color: #444; }
.intlButton i {
  background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, .7); 
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 4px; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be an `ul`. Even without CSS you will have a navigational structure. How about giving your nav a better suited name like `.nav-localization`?

Also I guess the `div`'s inside your links will act like as sub navigations? These would be `ul`'s as well then.

I've added comments to get rid of the whitespace between the list-items, since you're using `display: inline-block;`. This looks quite *dirty*, but it's the best solution for the whitespace issue and inline-block.

Here is the markup, I'd go for:

```
<ul class="nav-localization">
    <li class="locale">
        <a href="#">
            North America
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav americas"></ul>
    </li><!--
 --><li class="locale">
        <a href="#">
            Europe
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav europe"></ul>
    </li><!--
 --><li class="locale">
        <a href="#">
            Korea
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-nav korea"></ul>
    </li><!--
 --><li class="intlButton">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**How you would select:**

```
.nav-localization {}

.nav-localization > li {}

.nav-localization > li > a {}

.nav-localization .sub-nav {}
```